# Long Pause After Asyncio Context Manager

Tags: python, python-asyncio, binance

Just trying to get my head around `asyncio` with some simple examples:

```
import asyncio
from binance import AsyncClient, BinanceSocketManager

async def main():

    # initialise the client
    client = await AsyncClient.create()
    bsm = BinanceSocketManager(client)

    # create listener using async with
    # this will exit and close the connection after 5 messages
    async with bsm.trade_socket('BTCUSDT') as ts:
        for _ in range(5):
            res = await ts.recv()
            print(f'{_} recv {res}')

    print('Hello')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Output:

```
0 recv {'e': 'trade', 'E': 1620125896291, 's': 'BTCUSDT', 't': 807604863, 'p': '56336.87000000', 'q': '0.00044900', 'b': 5772457377, 'a': 5772457449, 'T': 1620125896291, 'm': True, 'M': True}
1 recv {'e': 'trade', 'E': 1620125896345, 's': 'BTCUSDT', 't': 807604864, 'p': '56336.88000000', 'q': '0.00099900', 'b': 5772457451, 'a': 5772457310, 'T': 1620125896345, 'm': False, 'M': True}
2 recv {'e': 'trade', 'E': 1620125896556, 's': 'BTCUSDT', 't': 807604865, 'p': '56336.87000000', 'q': '0.01220300', 'b': 5772457377, 'a': 5772457460, 'T': 1620125896555, 'm': True, 'M': True}
3 recv {'e': 'trade', 'E': 1620125896579, 's': 'BTCUSDT', 't': 807604866, 'p': '56336.88000000', 'q': '0.01037100', 'b': 5772457461, 'a': 5772457310, 'T': 1620125896579, 'm': False, 'M': True}
4 recv {'e': 'trade', 'E': 1620125896583, 's': 'BTCUSDT', 't': 807604867, 'p': '56336.88000000', 'q': '0.00091100', 'b': 5772457462, 'a': 5772457310, 'T': 1620125896583, 'm': False, 'M': True}
Hello
```

The lines starting with 0, 1, 2, 3 and 4 appear pretty much immediately, whenever a trade event is received.  However, there is quite a long pause (around 1-5 seconds, it varies upon each run) before `Hello` is printed.  What is the reason for that pause?

Comment: Context manager cleans up before moving on outside `with` block, maybe it's `bsm.trade_socket` that's taking up time - especially if networks are involved with asyncio. Not directly related but you might want to read more on [this](https://vorpus.org/blog/some-thoughts-on-asynchronous-api-design-in-a-post-asyncawait-world).

Answer (score 0):

Change "for _ in range(5):" to While True:

Then add this below your print('Hello') "await client.close_connection()"

Answer (score -1):

## this will exit and close the connection after 5 messages

for _ in range(5):

Change 5 to > number.

If my understanding is correct to your problem.

Comment: I think it's trying to close the connection that's why it's having a pause.